# Input string was not in correct format error when parsing to int

Tags: c#

I get error "Input string was not in correct format" when parsing to int.
But string is in correct format. I'm adding screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Is something really wrong here or did my vacation time come ?

Comment: Looks fine. There might be some unprintable characters in the string which cause problems. Can you try to create a [mcve]?

Comment: As @Heinzi said, there must be some hidden characters in your string. Try `int.Parse(a.Substring 0,4)`

Comment: this is madness but it worked with `int.Parse(a.Substring( 1,4))` and produced `2016`. thanks guys. @Pikoh, if you post as answer i'll mark it correct.

Comment: What is `a.Length`? It must be more than 4.

Comment: yes @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev. it's six. thanks.

Comment: Please, don't just use `a.Substring(1,4)` as a solution! If a *correct* string happens to come along, your code will silently drop the first digit, yielding an incorrect result. Instead, find out **why** your string is broken and **fix the cause instead of the symptom**.

Comment: You're completely right Heinzi. So I'll use @Jens Bornschein code to clear non numeric characters.

Comment: @Heinzi my suggestion was  `(0,4)` not  (`1,4`) so it would work with a correct string. Anyway you are right, it should be fixed before, depending on where that string is coming from

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it does not provide any substantial details required to solve it.

Comment: @Heinzi oh,now i see. OP is using (`1,4`). That is bad indeed.

Comment: @Pikoh, in my situtation 1,4 worked. This is why we must depend on indexes but clear non numeric characters instead. fix the cause instead of symptom like Heinzi refers. thanks all. it works now.

Comment: @Doruk yes, but as Heinzi explained that would fail if you get a string without that leading character. It's better to clean the string as you now are doing. Glad it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there must be some hidden characters in your `a` string variable (Carriage Return maybe?). Try `int.Parse(a.Substring 0,4)` as usually they are at the end of the string.

You could also clean the input where you are getting that value from.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are doing multiple conversions. Are you sure it's a ("2016") that is causing the error? 
if yes, then there must be hidden characters as other have suggested. The a.substring(0,4) would indeed remove any trailing characters. But if the first character is a hidden char, it would not.

```
string output = new string(input.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

should clear out any possible hidden characters.

Comment: yeah. i'm sure.

Comment: did you try to clean up a with the line I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(a);
```

Furthermore you can try to use the `.ToString()` Methode of `a` to make it run more stable.

---

You can additionaly try to clear the string from all "non number" chars using Rexex:

```
/// <summary>
/// RegEx to extract all non numeric values.
/// </summary>
private static readonly Regex rxNonDigits = new Regex(@"[^\d.,-]+");
```

Use it as follows to clear:

```
String a2 = rxNonDigits.Replace(a, "");
```

Comment: What difference do you expect between `int.Parse` and `Convert.ToIn32`?

Comment: I've added another idea for a “String” clearing method underneath.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using REST API with JSON or passing whole string in query string i.e [JSON formatted string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191864(v=vs.110).aspx), then you should use

```
a = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(a, null).ToString();
x = int.Parse(a);
```